# Integral domain that is not Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

There exist finitely generated algebras over a field that are integral but not Cohen-Macaulay (bottom of http://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Cohen-Macaulay_ring). What is an example?